# Can I check if a view exists on the screen with KIF?

Tags: ios, kif

I am making a "before each" step and I am wanting to do steps to logout.  I can't find anything about checking if an element exists before I try to touch it, then if it doesn't exist do something else.  Is it possible to do this with KIF without having a reference to the object I want to check for?

Something like:

```
if([tester elementExistsWithAccesibilityLabel:@"backButton"])
{
    [tester tapViewWithAccessibilityLabel:@"backButton"];
}
else
{
    [tester tapViewwithAccesibilityLabel:@"Logout"];
}
```

Answer (score 19):

I would suggest to try this approach:

```
if([[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] accessibilityElementWithLabel:@"backButton"] != nil) {
     [tester tapViewWithAccessibilityLabel:@"backButton"];
} else {
     [tester tapViewWithAccessibilityLabel:@"Logout"];
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work if the view is in the view hierarchy but is not currently viewable on the screen when another VC has been presented.

Answer (score 5):

These methods do the trick. Add them to a category for KIFUITestActor.

```
#import "UIApplication-KIFAdditions.h" 
#import "UIAccessibilityElement-KIFAdditions.h"
#import "NSError-KIFAdditions.h"

- (BOOL)existsViewWithAccessibilityLabel:(NSString *)label
{
    UIView *view = nil;
    UIAccessibilityElement *element = nil;
    return [self existsAccessibilityElement:&element view:&view withLabel:label value:nil traits:UIAccessibilityTraitNone tappable:YES];
}

- (BOOL)existsAccessibilityElement:(UIAccessibilityElement **)element view:(out UIView **)view withLabel:(NSString *)label value:(NSString *)value traits:(UIAccessibilityTraits)traits tappable:(BOOL)mustBeTappable
{
    KIFTestStepResult (^executionBlock)(NSError **) = ^(NSError **error) {
        return [UIAccessibilityElement accessibilityElement:element view:view withLabel:label value:value traits:traits tappable:mustBeTappable error:error] ? KIFTestStepResultSuccess : KIFTestStepResultWait;
    };

    NSDate *startDate = [NSDate date];
    KIFTestStepResult result;
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSTimeInterval timeout = 10.0;

    while ((result = executionBlock(&error)) == KIFTestStepResultWait && -[startDate timeIntervalSinceNow] < timeout) {
        CFRunLoopRunInMode([[UIApplication sharedApplication] currentRunLoopMode] ?: kCFRunLoopDefaultMode, 0.1, false);
    }

    if (result == KIFTestStepResultWait) {
        error = [NSError KIFErrorWithUnderlyingError:error format:@"The step timed out after %.2f seconds: %@", timeout, error.localizedDescription];
        result = KIFTestStepResultFailure;
    }

    return (result == KIFTestStepResultSuccess) ? YES : NO;
}
```

It works for me very well.

Comment: This worked for me, but remember to put it within an `@autorelease{ ... }`.

Comment: Added necessary header imports to make the code compile correctly.

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone is still looking for an answer, there is a family of methods in KIF that does just that `KIFUITestActor-ConditionalTests.h`:

```
- (BOOL)tryFindingViewWithAccessibilityLabel:(NSString *)label error:(out NSError **)error;

- (BOOL)tryFindingViewWithAccessibilityLabel:(NSString *)label traits:(UIAccessibilityTraits)traits error:(out NSError **)error;

- (BOOL)tryFindingViewWithAccessibilityLabel:(NSString *)label value:(NSString *)value traits:(UIAccessibilityTraits)traits error:(out NSError **)error;

- (BOOL)tryFindingTappableViewWithAccessibilityLabel:(NSString *)label error:(out NSError **)error;

- (BOOL)tryFindingTappableViewWithAccessibilityLabel:(NSString *)label traits:(UIAccessibilityTraits)traits error:(out NSError **)error;

- (BOOL)tryFindingTappableViewWithAccessibilityLabel:(NSString *)label value:(NSString *)value traits:(UIAccessibilityTraits)traits error:(out NSError **)error;

- (BOOL)tryFindingAccessibilityElement:(out UIAccessibilityElement **)element view:(out UIView **)view withIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier tappable:(BOOL)mustBeTappable error:(out NSError **)error;

- (BOOL)tryFindingAccessibilityElement:(out UIAccessibilityElement **)element view:(out UIView **)view withElementMatchingPredicate:(NSPredicate *)predicate tappable:(BOOL)mustBeTappable error:(out NSError **)error;
```

If you're using the Accessibility Identifier additions (`pod 'KIF/IdentifierTests'`) there's also the very handy equivalent method:
`- (BOOL) tryFindingViewWithAccessibilityIdentifier:(NSString *) accessibilityIdentifier;`

Answer (score 2):

For swift 3:

```
/** return true when the view is found */
func searchForElement(_ label:String) -> Bool{
    do {
        try tester().tryFindingView(withAccessibilityLabel: label)
        return true
    } catch {
        return false

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
@try {
   if([tester waitForViewWithAccessibilityLabel:@"backButton"])
   {
      [tester tapViewWithAccessibilityLabel:@"backButton"];
   }
@catch (NSException *exception )
{
   [tester tapViewwithAccesibilityLabel:@"Logout"];
}
@finally 
{
   NSLOG(@"User logged out.");
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work because the exception is handled first my KIF's code and never reaches the `@try` block in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I made this function that seems to do the trick in a pinch, but it would have some issues if multiple integration tests were simultaneously relying on the global default timeout. So far, seems to work for me.

```
static CGFloat CPKIFDefaultTimeout = 2

- (BOOL)elementExistsWithAccessibilityLabel:(NSString *)accessibilityLabel {
    [KIFTestActor setDefaultTimeout:0.0];
    BOOL result = [tester waitForViewWithAccessibilityLabel:accessibilityLabel] ? YES : NO;
    [KIFTestActor CPKIFDefaultTimeout];
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Not work for Xocde8.2. The test stops at the line: tester waitForViewWithAccessibilityLabel:accessibilityLabel.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, none of these worked for me... However I have a solution

Checkout [this gist.](https://gist.github.com/Jugale/54f5d5cf13d25353f7b0)

What I've done is taken KIF's code and just removed their error checking - works like a charm for me.

This won't fail your tests when it can't find an element!

Answer (score 0):

If using the Swift you can simply use the `viewTester().tryFindingView()`:

```
if viewTester().usingLabel("backButton").tryFindingView() {
    // back button exists
    viewTester().usingLabel("backButton").tap()
} else {
    // back button does not exist
    viewTester().usingLabel("Logout").tap()
}
```